# "USB device has malfunctioned" with no USB devices attached

Tags: usb, windows-server-2003

I have a Win2k3 x64 server. I just took the system down to upgrade from a Promise RAID controller to an Areca. I created the new RAID array and cloned the system over fine, and the system is back up. However, I am having a problem with all external devices. Basically, every couple of minutes, I am notified that a USB device has malfunctioned; however, there are absolutely no USB devices connected to the box. When I connect a USB device to any of the ports, the system does not attach the device.

I don't know if this may be related, but eSATA devices attached to my Promise eSATA controller are also not being recognized at all.

It seems odd to me since all that really happened as far as the system is concerned (correct me if I'm wrong) is that it was shut down and brought back up. I have tried rebooting and reinstalling the USB root hubs, all to no avail. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: What does the notification look like? Is it a baloon tooltip or a messagebox? Can you click it?

Comment: It is a tooltip in the notification area. I can click it, but then it just goes away.